# Run simultaneous animations in only CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, stylesheet

I'm trying to run two animations at the same time. Everything looks perfect to me, but it acts really wacky and I can't figure out why. I want to keep the entire thing in CSS.

As posted in the comments, Here's the current version of the working page: fallowproduction.com/cowabduction/csspractice1.html

It currently only works 100% in chrome, or I suppose Safari.

The CSS sheet is here: fallowproduction.com/cowabduction/practice1StyleSheet.css

If you notice, the cow on the far left is the one I'm working on. He's supposed to move upwards when the UFO is over him (it's all timed correctly as far as I can tell). However, instead he just slowly disappears

Here's the excerpt from the code:

```
    .ufo {
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 25;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width= 225px; 
height= 142px;
position: absolute;

animation: move_ufo 180s ease 0 1;
-moz-animation: move_ufo 180s ease 0 1; /* Firefox 4 */ 
-webkit-animation: move_ufo 180s ease 0 1; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: move_ufo 180s ease 0 1; /* Opera */

}


@-webkit-keyframes move_ufo {
    0% { left: 0px; top: 0px; }   /* Move to cow6 */
    1.75% { left: 456px; top: 10px; }
    4.55% { left: 456px; top: 10px; }   /* Move to cow2 */
    6.29% { left: 103px; top: 92px; }
    9.09% { left: 103px; top: 92px; }   /* Move to cow7 */
    10.84% { left: 566px; top: 110px; }
    13.64% { left: 566px; top: 110px; }   /* Move to cow4 */
    15.38% { left: 316px; top: -1px; }
    18.18% { left: 316px; top: -1px; }   /* Move to cow1*/
    19.93% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }
    22.73% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }   /* Move to cow8*/
    24.48% { left: 166px; top: 154px; }
    27.27% { left: 166px; top: 154px; }   /* Move to cow5*/
    29.02% { left: 458px; top: 10px; }
    31.82% { left: 458px; top: 10px; }   /* Move to cow10 */
    33.57% { left: 197px; top: -16px; }
    36.36% { left: 197px; top: -16px; }   /* Move to cow3*/
    38.11% { left: 217px; top: 68px; }
    40.91% { left: 217px; top: 68px; }   /* Move to cow9*/
    42.66% { left: 573px; top: -2px; }
    45.45% { left: 573px; top: -2px; }   /* Move */
    47.20% { left: 333px; top: 55px; }
    50.00% { left: 371px; top: 48px; }   /* Move to cow1*/
    51.75% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }
    54.55% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }   /* Move to cow7*/
    56.29% { left: 566px; top: 110px; }
    59.09% { left: 566px; top: 110px; }   /* Move to cow4*/
    60.84% { left: 316px; top: -1px; }
    63.64% { left: 316px; top: -1px; }   /* Move to cow8*/
    65.38% { left: 166px; top: 154px; }
    68.18% { left: 166px; top: 154px; }   /* Move to cow6*/
    69.93% { left: 456px; top: 10px; }
    72.73% { left: 456px; top: 10px; }   /* Move to cow10*/
    74.48% { left: 197px; top: -16px; }
    77.27% { left: 197px; top: -16px; }   /* Move to cow2 */
    79.02% { left: 103px; top: 92px; }
    81.82% { left: 103px; top: 92px; }   /* Move to cow5*/
    83.57% { left: 458px; top: 10px; }
    86.36% { left: 458px; top: 10px; }   /* Move to cow9*/
    88.11% { left: 573px; top: -2px; }
    90.91% { left: 573px; top: -2px; }   /* Move to cow3*/
    92.66% { left: 217px; top: 68px; }
    95.45% { left: 217px; top: 68px; }   /* Move */
    97.20% { left: 300px; top: 25px; }   
    100% { left: 0px; top: 0px; }   /* Original Location */

}





/* Cows and tractor beams */

.cow1 {
left: 80px;
top: 450px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;

/* Animation */
animation: move_cow1 180s;
-moz-animation: move_cow1 180s; /* Firefox 4 */ 
-webkit-animation: move_cow1 180s ease 0 1; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: move_cow1 180s; /* Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes move_cow1 {
    0% { left: 80px; top: 450px; } 
    19.93% { left: 80px; top: 450px; } /* UFO is at cow1 */
    22.73% { left: 80px; top: 61px; }  /* cow1 is being lifted */
    22.74% { opacity: 0; ; } /* cow1 disappears */

    51.75% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }
    54.55% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }   /* Move to cow7*/
    100% { left: 80px; top: 450px; }

}
```

Comment: Can you post this in a [working](http://sscce.org/) fiddle?

Comment: And by the way, this is where you can do nice fiddles : http://jsfiddle.net/. There is not even a single line of html in your question, how are we supposed to understand what you want to do...

Comment: I've never used fiddle before, but I can provide a working URL.
http://fallowproduction.com/cowabduction/csspractice1.html
The CSS sheet is here:
http://fallowproduction.com/cowabduction/practice1StyleSheet.css

If you notice, the cow on the far left is the one I'm working on. He's supposed to move upwards when the UFO is over him (it's all timed correctly as far as I can tell). However, instead he just slowly disappears.

Comment: I figured it out! You have to append "opacity: 100" 8 lines from the bottom, or the cow disappears before the UFO arrives. I can't add an answer because the post is too recent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move_cow1 {
    0% { opacity: 1; left: 80px; top: 450px; } 
    19.93% { opacity: 1; left: 80px; top: 450px; } /* UFO is at cow1 */
    22.73% { opacity: 1; left: 80px; top: 61px; }  /* cow1 is being lifted */
    22.74% { opacity: 0; } /* cow1 disappears */

    51.75% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }
    54.55% { left: 4px; top: 61px; }   /* Move to cow7*/
    100% { left: 80px; top: 450px; }

}
```